# How to move filter function inside of the directive?

Tags: angularjs

So I have a custom filter I made it looks like this:

```
.filter('iwSearch', function() {
        return function(items, term) {
            if (term !== undefined) {
                var newTerm = term.split(' ');
                var resultsArr = items.filter(function(item) {
                    // Check against new term whether it's a match.
                    var matches = 0;
                    var newItem = item.split(' ');
                    for (var i = 0; i < newItem.length; i++) {
                        //iterate over search term and check that all matches
                        if (newItem[i].indexOf(newTerm[i]) !== -1) matches++
                    }
                    return (matches >= newTerm.length);
                });
                return resultsArr;
            } else {
                return items;
            }
        }
    })
```

And I have this directive:

```
.directive('iwAutoComplete', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div  class="btn-group btn-xs" dropdown keyboard-nav>' +
                            '<input dropdown-toggle'+
                                'iw-click'+
                                'iw-submit="addFirst()"'+
                                'ng-model="available_filters_query"'+
                                'ng-disabled="disabled"'+
                                'placeholder="Add New Field"'+
                            '>'+
                            '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="simple-btn-keyboard-nav">'+
                                '<li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in availableFilters | iwSearch: available_filters_query">'+
                                    '<a href="#" ng-click="addField(item)">{{item | toUserListHeader}}</a>'+
                                '</li>'+
                            '</ul>'+
                    '</div>'
        };
    });
```

So how can I move `iwSearch` filter inside of my `iwAutoComplete` directive? Is it even possible? Or is there a good tutorial/refference on how to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by you wanted to include in the directive..if its added to the `app` module then you could easily use that filter..or you are getting any issue while trying this..please update the question..

Comment: I want my filter to be a part of directive, not a separate module to the app. So I could use variables from the filter inside of the other functions, not exclusively in the filter.

Comment: then make it as function & place it inside link function scope, then you could use that function as a filter...

Comment: @PankajParkar do I need to apply it as a usual filter? Or somehow else?

Comment: it will work as usual filter..as like you were using it when it was filter